# Parsing JSON array of List of Array

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have `JSON` string that looks like this that I am trying to `deserialize`:

```
"[{\"asset\":\"AAPL\",\"instumentProfile\":{\"2023-06-30\":[50.0,60.0,65.0,70.0,75.0,80.0,85.0,90.0,95.0,100.0,105.0,110.0,115.0,120.0,125.0,130.0,135.0,140.0,145.0,150.0,152.5,155.0,157.5,160.0,162.5,165.0,167.5,170.0,172.5,175.0,177.5,180.0,182.5,185.0,187.5,190.0,192.5,195.0,197.5,200.0,202.5,205.0,207.5,210.0,212.5,215.0,220.0,225.0,230.0,235.0,240.0,245.0,250.0,255.0],\"2023-07-07\":[50.0,60.0,65.0,70.0,75.0,80.0,85.0,90.0,95.0,100.0,105.0,110.0,115.0,120.0,125.0,130.0,135.0,140.0,145.0,148.0,149.0,150.0,155.0,157.5,160.0,162.5,165.0,167.5,170.0,172.5,175.0,177.5,180.0,182.5,185.0,187.5,190.0,192.5,195.0,197.5,200.0,202.5,205.0,207.5,210.0,212.5,215.0,220.0,225.0,230.0,235.0,240.0,245.0,250.0,255.0],\"2023-07-14\":[50.0,60.0,65.0,70.0,75.0,80.0,85.0,90.0,95.0,100.0,105.0,110.0,115.0,120.0,125.0,130.0,135.0,140.0,145.0,150.0,155.0,160.0,165.0,170.0,175.0,180.0,185.0,190.0,195.0,200.0,205.0,210.0,215.0,220.0,225.0,230.0,235.0,240.0,245.0,250.0,255.0],\"2023-07-21\":[50.0,55.0,60.0,65.0,70.0,75.0,80.0,85.0,90.0,95.0,100.0,105.0,110.0,115.0,120.0,125.0,130.0,135.0,140.0,145.0,150.0,155.0,157.5,160.0,162.5,165.0,167.5,170.0,172.5,175.0,177.5,180.0,182.5,185.0,187.5,190.0,192.5,195.0,197.5,200.0,202.5,205.0,207.5,210.0,215.0,220.0,225.0,230.0,235.0,240.0,245.0,250.0,255.0,260.0,270.0,280.0],\"2023-07-28\":[50.0,60.0,65.0,70.0,75.0,80.0,85.0,90.0,95.0,100.0,105.0,110.0,115.0,120.0,125.0,130.0,135.0,140.0,145.0,150.0,155.0,160.0,165.0,170.0,175.0,180.0,185.0,190.0,195.0,200.0,205.0,210.0,215.0,220.0,225.0,230.0,235.0,240.0,245.0,250.0,255.0],\"2023-08-04\":[50.0,60.0,65.0,70.0,75.0,80.0,85.0,90.0,95.0,100.0,105.0,110.0,115.0,120.0,125.0,130.0,135.0,140.0,145.0,150.0,155.0,160.0,165.0,170.0,175.0,180.0,185.0,190.0,195.0,200.0,205.0,210.0,215.0,220.0,225.0,230.0,235.0,240.0,245.0,250.0,255.0],\"2023-08-18\":[50.0,55.0,60.0,65.0,70.0,75.0,80.0,85.0,90.0,95.0,100.0,105.0,110.0,115.0,120.0,125.0,130.0,135.0,140.0,145.0,150.0,155.0,160.0,165.0,170.0,175.0,180.0,185.0,190.0,195.0,200.0,205.0,210.0,215.0,220.0,225.0,230.0,235.0,240.0,245.0,250.0,255.0,260.0,265.0,270.0,275.0,280.0,285.0],\"2023-09-15\":[65.0,70.0,75.0,80.0,85.0,90.0,95.0,100.0,105.0,110.0,115.0,120.0,125.0,130.0,135.0,140.0,145.0,150.0,155.0,160.0,165.0,170.0,175.0,180.0,185.0,190.0,195.0,200.0,205.0,210.0,220.0,230.0,240.0,250.0,260.0,270.0,280.0,290.0,300.0],\"2023-10-20\":[55.0,60.0,65.0,70.0,75.0,80.0,85.0,90.0,95.0,100.0,105.0,110.0,115.0,120.0,125.0,130.0,135.0,140.0,145.0,150.0,155.0,160.0,165.0,170.0,175.0,180.0,185.0,190.0,195.0,200.0,205.0,210.0,215.0,220.0,225.0,230.0,235.0,240.0,245.0,250.0,255.0,260.0,265.0,270.0,275.0,280.0,285.0,290.0,295.0],\"2023-11-17\":[50.0,55.0,60.0,65.0,70.0,75.0,80.0,85.0,90.0,95.0,100.0,105.0,110.0,115.0,120.0,125.0,130.0,135.0,140.0,145.0,150.0,155.0,160.0,165.0,170.0,175.0,180.0,185.0,190.0,195.0,200.0,205.0,210.0,215.0,220.0,225.0,230.0,235.0,240.0,245.0,250.0,255.0,260.0,265.0,270.0,275.0,280.0,285.0,290.0,300.0],\"2023-12-15\":[65.0,70.0,75.0,80.0,85.0,90.0,95.0,100.0,105.0,110.0,115.0,120.0,125.0,130.0,135.0,140.0,145.0,150.0,155.0,160.0,165.0,170.0,175.0,180.0,185.0,190.0,195.0,200.0,205.0,210.0,215.0,220.0,225.0,230.0,235.0,240.0,245.0,250.0,255.0,260.0,265.0,270.0,275.0,280.0,285.0,290.0,295.0],\"2024-01-19\":[50.0,55.0,60.0,65.0,70.0,75.0,80.0,85.0,90.0,95.0,100.0,105.0,110.0,115.0,120.0,125.0,130.0,135.0,140.0,145.0,150.0,155.0,160.0,165.0,170.0,175.0,180.0,185.0,190.0,195.0,200.0,205.0,210.0,215.0,220.0,225.0,230.0,235.0,240.0,245.0,250.0,255.0,260.0,265.0,270.0,275.0,280.0,285.0,290.0,300.0,310.0,320.0],\"2024-03-15\":[50.0,55.0,60.0,65.0,70.0,75.0,80.0,85.0,90.0,95.0,100.0,105.0,110.0,115.0,120.0,125.0,130.0,135.0,140.0,145.0,150.0,155.0,160.0,165.0,170.0,175.0,180.0,185.0,190.0,195.0,200.0,205.0,210.0,215.0,220.0,225.0,230.0,235.0,240.0,245.0,250.0,255.0,260.0,265.0,270.0,275.0,280.0,285.0,290.0,300.0,310.0],\"2024-06-21\":[50.0,55.0,60.0,65.0,70.0,75.0,80.0,85.0,90.0,95.0,100.0,105.0,110.0,115.0,120.0,125.0,130.0,135.0,140.0,145.0,150.0,155.0,160.0,165.0,170.0,175.0,180.0,185.0,190.0,195.0,200.0,205.0,210.0,215.0,220.0,225.0,230.0,235.0,240.0,245.0,250.0,255.0,260.0,265.0,270.0,275.0,280.0,285.0,290.0,300.0,310.0,320.0],\"2024-09-20\":[50.0,55.0,60.0,65.0,70.0,75.0,80.0,85.0,90.0,95.0,100.0,105.0,110.0,115.0,120.0,125.0,130.0,135.0,140.0,145.0,150.0,155.0,160.0,165.0,170.0,175.0,180.0,185.0,190.0,195.0,200.0,205.0,210.0,215.0,220.0,225.0,230.0,235.0,240.0,245.0,250.0,255.0,260.0,265.0,270.0,280.0,290.0,300.0,310.0],\"2024-12-20\":[50.0,55.0,60.0,65.0,70.0,75.0,80.0,85.0,90.0,95.0,100.0,105.0,110.0,115.0,120.0,125.0,130.0,135.0,140.0,145.0,150.0,155.0,160.0,165.0,170.0,175.0,180.0,185.0,190.0,195.0,200.0,205.0,210.0,215.0,220.0,225.0,230.0,235.0,240.0,245.0,250.0,255.0,260.0,265.0,270.0,275.0,280.0,285.0,290.0,295.0,300.0,305.0,310.0],\"2025-01-17\":[50.0,55.0,60.0,65.0,70.0,75.0,80.0,85.0,90.0,95.0,100.0,105.0,110.0,115.0,120.0,125.0,130.0,135.0,140.0,145.0,150.0,155.0,160.0,165.0,170.0,175.0,180.0,185.0,190.0,195.0,200.0,205.0,210.0,215.0,220.0,225.0,230.0,235.0,240.0,245.0,250.0,255.0,260.0,265.0,270.0,275.0,280.0,285.0,290.0,300.0,310.0],\"2025-06-20\":[50.0,55.0,60.0,65.0,70.0,75.0,80.0,85.0,90.0,95.0,100.0,105.0,110.0,115.0,120.0,125.0,130.0,135.0,140.0,145.0,150.0,155.0,160.0,165.0,170.0,175.0,180.0,185.0,190.0,195.0,200.0,205.0,210.0,215.0,220.0,225.0,230.0,235.0,240.0,245.0,250.0,260.0,270.0,280.0,290.0,300.0,310.0],\"2025-12-19\":[50.0,55.0,60.0,65.0,70.0,75.0,80.0,85.0,90.0,95.0,100.0,105.0,110.0,115.0,120.0,125.0,130.0,135.0,140.0,145.0,150.0,155.0,160.0,165.0,170.0,175.0,180.0,185.0,190.0,195.0,200.0,205.0,210.0,215.0,220.0,225.0,230.0,235.0,240.0,245.0,250.0,260.0,270.0,280.0,290.0,300.0,310.0]}}]"
```

When I try to parse this JSON with the code below, `data.Asset` is correct, but `data.instrumentProfile` is null. **Not sure what is wrong**?

```
public class VWInstrumentProfile
{
    public List<double> Strikes { get; set; }
}

public class JsonParsedData
{
    public string Asset { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, VWInstrumentProfile> instrumentProfile { get; set; }
}

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.Count; i++)
{
    var jsonParsedData = JObject.Parse(jsonArray[i].ToString());
    var jsonParsed = JObject.Parse(jsonParsedData.ToString()).ToString();
    JsonParsedData data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonParsedData>(jsonParsed);

    Console.WriteLine("Asset: " + data.Asset);

    foreach (var profile in data.instrumentProfile) // This is null
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Date: " + profile.Key);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: The name in the JSON is **`instumentProfile`** not `InstrumentProfiles`.  No trailing `s`.

Comment: Thanks, but if I change it (see OP) it still doesn't work. I wonder if I have to use properties on  the classes to help newtonsoft put the right thing in the right place?

Comment: Your post is still wrong.  The word in the JSON is misspelled: "instument" instead of "instrument".  Which is wrong?

Comment: The `instrumentProfile` (or `instumentProfile`; choose one) should be modeled as a `Dictionary<string, List<double>>`; there is no `strikes` property in the JSON for the deserializer to find.

Comment: instumentProfile is what the JSON is returning, and is mispelled. Eagle eyes! Now I get an error on the deserialization:   JsonParsedData data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonParsedData>(jsonParsed);

Comment: You guys are just too good. Thanks Heretic that works. What a gigantic waste of four hours. Sigh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct data model is:

```
public class JsonParsedData
{
    public string Asset { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("instumentProfile")]
    public Dictionary<string, List<double>> InstrumentProfile { get; set; } = new ();
}
```

And the root JSON container is an array, so deserialize to a `List<JsonParsedData>` like so:

```
var array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonParsedData>>(json);
foreach (var (date, values) in array.SelectMany(p => p.InstrumentProfile)) // var (date, values) uses deconstructors from C#7 
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Date: {date}, Values: {string.Join(",", values)}");
}
```

Notes:

- The property name in the JSON is misspelled as `instumentProfile` not `instrumentProfile`.  You might prefer to fix the JSON rather than add `[JsonProperty("instumentProfile")]` to your model.
- There is no need to parse to an intermediate `JArray`.  The list can be deserialized directly.

Demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5KJACI).